# php echo gzipped file cutting off half way through

Tags: php, gzip

I am trying to send gzipped content from the server. I have gzipped a file ([get it here](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B2-EDNVQTZIdMDI3MmM5ODktODdmMi00MmU2LTkyNmEtZmRmNjQ4Mzk1ZTQw&hl=en_US)), and am trying to `echo` it out I have set the right headers (I think). The output starts of correctly, but only outputs the first so many lines.

```
<?php
  $file = file_get_contents('kendo/js/kendo.all.js.gz');
  header('Content-Encoding: gzip');
  header('Content-Length: '.strlen($file)); # gets the correct filesize of my gzipped file
  echo $file;
?>
```

Is there something wrong with my method?

Comment: You should probably have a `content-type` header. You can also try turning `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` and after the file fails to download, open what you have downloaded in a text editor to look for php errors.

Comment: seems like a false alarm. I am running the same code now and seems to work. Must have been some browser/server caching issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted code works - there was another error, I am assuming a browser cache issue - but that has resolved itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your content length is the length of the gzipped file and not the actual .js file.

Hence the content gets truncated once the length of the gzipped file is reached. Consider using ob_gzhandler

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php

Comment: i think the content-length refers to the length of data sent to the client, not how much is unpacked. Thanks for the suggested gzhandler, that will probably be an all round better approach.

Comment: yes! The length of the data sent to the client is the length of your gzip file and not the length of actual .js file. However you are trying to  echo the contents of the .js file is what I am trying to say.

Comment: no - I am echoing the contents of the gzipped file - so it looks like a load of garbled text, until the browser decodes it. It seems to be working now, must have been server/browser cache issue. Cheers

Comment: but how was it working in the first place? If you set the content encoding as gzip then the browser should decode it (atleast most modern browsers should). Did you get rid of the content encoding to make it work? Just curious.

Comment: it works as it is posted. I thought there was an error, because I was getting chopped off version, but now I realise that must have been browser/server cache, and not the output of the above script - which works. It works because the binary contents of the gzipped file are read into a variable and measured. Then we tell the browser via a header how long the (gzipped) data we are sending is and the browser downloads it all, then unzips after it has downloaded the `content-length` specified. We don't need to tell it the uncompressed size at all. Finally, I echo byte for byte the gzipped file. :)